# YouTrack java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - Teamcity integration

Tags: youtrack

We are getting the error below which is causing YouTrack to crash.

We are using YouTrack to scan TeamCity for changes which I beleive is causing the issue below.

How much memory should YouTrack need to run with TeamCity integration and which config should we use to allow for this increase memory usage?

### Error Message:

```
26 Sep 2011 22:20:00,043 ERROR [SuccessfulBuild_Then] [ssor0] Error while processing Teamcity integration for project [Connectors]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.init(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInflater(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.parse(ServiceFinder.java:455)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.access$300(ServiceFinder.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:529)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:295)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProviderAndServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:274)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:181)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.InjectableProviderFactory.configure(InjectableProviderFactory.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:209)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:150)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:472)
    at jetbrains.charisma.teamcity.rest.TeamcityRest.<init>(TeamcityRest.java:60)
    at jetbrains.charisma.teamcity.rest.TeamcityRest.<init>(TeamcityRest.java:66)
    at jetbrains.charisma.teamcity.rest.TeamcityRest.create(TeamcityRest.java:249)
    at jetbrains.charisma.teamcity.persistence.TeamcityBuildConfMappingImpl.process(TeamcityBuildConfMappingImpl.java:140)
    at jetbrains.charisma.teamcity.persistence.TeamcityIntegration_watchNewSuccessfulBuild_Then.run(TeamcityIntegration_watchNewSuccessfulBuild_Then.java:26)
    at jetbrains.mps.businessRules.runtime.impl.RuleJobImpl._execute(RuleJobImpl.java:68)
    at jetbrains.mps.businessRules.runtime.impl.RuleJobImpl.access$000(RuleJobImpl.java:14)
    at jetbrains.mps.businessRules.runtime.impl.RuleJobImpl$1.run(RuleJobImpl.java:46)
    at jetbrains.mps.businessRules.runtime.TransactionalExecutor.execute(TransactionalExecutor.java:23)
    at webr.framework.controller.BeanContainerAwareExecutorWrapper.execute(BeanContainerAwareExecutorWrapper.java:23)
    at jetbrains.mps.businessRules.runtime.impl.RuleJobImpl.execute(RuleJobImpl.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:276)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.RunnableJob.execute(RunnableJob.java:25)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.Job.run(Job.java:75)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.ThreadJobProcessor.executeJob(ThreadJobProcessor.java:110)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.JobProcessorQueueAdapter.doJobs(JobProcessorQueueAdapter.java:86)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.ThreadJobProcessor.run(ThreadJobProcessor.java:89)
    at com.jetbrains.teamsys.core.execution.ThreadJobProcessor$1.run(ThreadJobProcessor.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Note: This error happens several times before completely crashing.

Comment: Find the size of the working set and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Josh, What's your way to run YouTrack (from .jar file, deploy .war file or as a windows service)? Alexander

Comment: Alex. V, I am running it as a windows service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh,

Try to increase JVM heap size that YouTrack uses:

Open YouTrack service properties ("YouTrack Web Service" under Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> Services) and set the following line into start parameters input

```
++JvmOptions "-Xmx1024M"
```